# NiFi Streaming to Spark on EMR

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-emr, apache-nifi

Using blog posts on [Apache](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/stream_processing_nifi_and_spark) and [Hortonworks](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/12708/nifi-feeding-data-to-spark-streaming.html) I've been able to stream from NiFi to Spark when both are located on the same machine.  Now I'm trying to stream from NiFi on one EC2 instance to an EMR cluster in the same subnet and security group and I'm running into problems.  The specific error being reported by the EMR Core machine is

```
Failed to receive data from NiFi
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189)
    at org.apache.nifi.remote.client.socket.EndpointConnectionPool.establishSiteToSiteConnection(EndpointConnectionPool.java:708)
    at org.apache.nifi.remote.client.socket.EndpointConnectionPool.establishSiteToSiteConnection(EndpointConnectionPool.java:682)
    at org.apache.nifi.remote.client.socket.EndpointConnectionPool.getEndpointConnection(EndpointConnectionPool.java:300)
    at org.apache.nifi.remote.client.socket.SocketClient.createTransaction(SocketClient.java:129)
    at org.apache.nifi.spark.NiFiReceiver$ReceiveRunnable.run(NiFiReceiver.java:149)
```

Using `netstat` on the core machine I see it does have an open TCP connection to the NiFi box on the site-to-site port (in my case 8090).  On the NiFi machine, in the nifi-app.log file, I see logs from the "Site-to-Site Worker Thread" about my core machine making connection (and nothing about any errors). So the initial connection seems to be successful but not much after that.

When I ran my Spark code locally I was on the NiFi EC2 instance, so I know that in general it works.  I'm just hitting something, probably security related, once the client is an EMR cluster.

As a work around I can post a file to S3 and then launch a Spark step from NiFi (using a Python script), but I'd much rather stream the data (and using Kafka isn't an option).  Has anyone else gotten streaming from NiFi to EMR working?

This post is similar: [Getting data from Nifi to spark streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907171/getting-data-from-nifi-to-spark-streaming) the difference being I have security turned off and I'm using http, not https (and I'm getting connection refused as opposed to a 401).

Edit:

nifi.properties:

```
# Site to Site properties
nifi.remote.input.host=
nifi.remote.input.secure=false
nifi.remote.input.socket.host=
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=8090
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true
nifi.remote.input.http.transaction.ttl=30 sec
```

Comment: So just to confirm, in nifi.properties you set nifi.remote.input.socket.port to 8090? and did you set a value for nifi.remote.input.host?

Comment: Yes and no.  I've edited the post with the site to site section of the properties file.

Comment: Ok you might want to try setting nifi.remote.input.host to a hostname of the EC2 instance (were NiFi is running) that would be resolvable by EMR. The site-to-site client in the spark streaming code is going to use the URL of the NiFi REST API to ask NiFi where to connect to for site-to-site, and NiFi is going to return the host and port from the site-to-site properties.

Comment: This worked!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bryan Bende](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5650316/bryan-bende) had the solution in a comment above: once I set `nifi.remote.input.host` to the IP address of the current machine streaming started working.